# Are there any tools for detecting code that behaves differently in different ruby versions?

Tags: ruby

Are there any tools that'd indicate that your code can produce different results in different ruby versions?

I'm envisaging something like

```
a = 1
b = 2
string = [1, 2, 3, 4].to_s
ToolName: Array#to_s has different behaviour in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9
```

Or failing that, inspect each variable at each line and indicate the first point at which they diverge under different versions, such as:

```
Ruby1.8:
a: 1 at line 1
b: 2 at line 2
string: "1234" at line 3

Ruby1.9:
a: 1 at line 1
b: 2 at line 2
string: "[1, 2, 3, 4]" at line 3

Ruby1.8 and Ruby1.9 first differ at line 3
```

Or is the only approach currently available to unit test your code, and make sure the tests pass on all versions of ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem [One9](http://tagaholic.me/2011/03/05/one9-upgrade-to-ruby-19-now.html) allows you to run a test suite, and it'll report which methods you've called that have changed between 1.8 and 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of anything, though a combination of rvm and good tests could help you tell.

rvm has the ability to cycle through all the rubies you have installed and execute a given script in each one. If that script was a suite of tests you might ferret out any version-based misdeeds. [`Set Actions`](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/set/ruby/) is where you'll want to read for that rvm goodness.